# How to stop bad requests from different ips?

Tags: php, wordpress

My website is hosted on wordpress and since yesterday I am continuously getting bad requests which is causing to down my website. Website showing "resource limit is reached" and in my cpanel entry process 40/40 and cpu usage 100/100.

**I am getting queries form lots of different ips at same time and not able to block them.**

**here are queries types**-

1. myurl/?tie=strange
2. myurl/?connect=once
3. myurl/?me=sight
4. myurl/?yard=gentle
5. myurl/?man=are
6. myurl/?man=are
7. myurl/?may=dance
8. myurl/?chief=add
9. myurl/?we=true

**Here are referring urls -**

1. https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=your
2. https://play.google.com/store/search?q=world
3. http: //www. zahnarzt-buhl.de/praxis/plugins/content/plugin_googlemap2_proxy.php?url=near
4. http: //www .w3.org/services/tidy?docAddr=measure

When I am blocking "?" (punctuation mark)in .htaccess file then my site works fine except urls containing punctuation mark.

**How to protect my website from these?**

Comment: Build a honey pot, capture the IP's /users that are sending that junk data and add them to your firewall.

Comment: Or place you website behind a service like [cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/)

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault.

Comment: Requests are coming from lots of different ips. Not possible to capture them.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use a firewall? You can block all these IPs with some simple rules...
Or you can add a small php script before your index that collect these ips and redirect the requests to google. Or you can use cloudflare or similar

Comment: Requests are coming from lots of different ips. Not possible block them.

Comment: Ok, then why not cloudflare? Easy to configure, and it filter all bad traffic

Comment: any other way to protect?

Comment: If you prefer a manual/custom way, you could add before the index a small script that collect all ips for you. If these requests are "much" in a small range time redirect to somewhere

Comment: can you tell me more about the script and process?

Comment: Yeah, just use Cloudflare. It has free plan, if this is what you worry about .